# how to control the line thickness in geom_line

Tags: r

I would like to control the thickness for lines in my plotting, however I ran into some difficulty. It seems like if I add `size=0.06` or `size=2` in `geom_line()`, it did not really change the line thickness to different size. Also it added strange legend in the output. how should I fix that?

I codes I used to do plotting are:

```
ggplot(data =df)+
       geom_line(aes(x = ADY, y = AVAL, color = PARAMCD, yaxs="d", xaxs="d", size=0.06))+
       geom_point(aes(x = ADY, y = AVAL))+
       scale_color_discrete(breaks=c("SYSBP", "DIABP", "PULSE"),name = "Vital signs", labels = c("Systolic BP", "Diastolic BP",  "Pulse"))+
       scale_colour_manual(values=c(DIABP="#512d69",SYSBP="#007254",PULSE="#fd9300"))
```

The output for `size=0.06` and `size =2` are:

[image]

[image]

Could someone give me some guidance on this? I don't want size to be shown on legend and I would like to control the thickness of the lines.Thanks.

The sample data can be build using codes:

```
df<- structure(list(ADY = c(-6, -6, -6, 1, 1, 1, 8, 8, 8, 15, 15, 
15, 22, 22, 22, 29, 29, 29, 43, 43, 43, 57, 57, 57, 64, 87, 87, 
87, 101, 101, 101), AVAL = c(66, 67, 127, 70, 58, 136, 68, 74, 
140, 145, 74, 58, 75, 72, 149, 82, 66, 143, 86, 60, 159, 64, 
87, 136, NA, 73, 58, 135, 141, 74, 74), PARAMCD = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, NA, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("DIABP", 
"SYSBP", "PULSE"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -31L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`size` should be outside `aes` for your case :

You can see the difference between between `size = 0.06` and `size = 2`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data =df)+
  geom_line(aes(x = ADY, y = AVAL, color = PARAMCD, yaxs="d", xaxs="d"), size=0.06) +
  geom_point(aes(x = ADY, y = AVAL))+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c(DIABP="#512d69",SYSBP="#007254",PULSE="#fd9300"))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(data =df)+
  geom_line(aes(x = ADY, y = AVAL, color = PARAMCD, yaxs="d", xaxs="d"),  size=2) +
  geom_point(aes(x = ADY, y = AVAL))+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c(DIABP="#512d69",SYSBP="#007254",PULSE="#fd9300"))
```

[image]